# Dual connections, examples

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\overline\nabla^{*} $ is a dual connection of connection $\overline\nabla $, and we have the Gauss equations:
\begin{align}
\notag
\overline\nabla^{*}_{X}Y=\nabla^{*}_{ X}Y + h^{*}(X,Y)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag
\overline\nabla_{X}Y=\nabla_{ X}Y + h(X,Y)
\end{align}
Are there examples of manifolds where $g(h^{*}(X,Y), h(X,Y))=0$